# getting django apps packaged as python eggs to work with django admin docs

Tags: python, django, egg

i've taken over a django (1.1) project which has a number of django apps installed as eggs (in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/). This works fine everywhere except for the django admin docs. Trying to view the docs for tags or filters here gets me:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.1.1-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admindocs/views.py" in load_all_installed_template_libraries
313.         libraries = [os.path.splitext(p)[0] for p in os.listdir(e) if p.endswith('.py') and p[0].isalpha()]

Exception Type: OSError at /admin/doc/tags/
Exception Value: (20, 'Not a directory')
```

where

```
e = '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_tinymce-1.5-py2.6.egg/tinymce/templatetags'
```

so basically the django admin docs can't auto load the eggs because they are zip archives, not directories.

having done some searching i think my options are:

1. unpack the eggs in place
2. adapt http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#using-eggs-with-mod-python (i'm using mod_wsgi)
3. hacking the django admindocs code to deal properly with eggs

none of these are probably really difficult but none are exactly appealing on a production server.
has anyone else dealt with this? what would you recommend?

Comment: ok i realised that i was asking the wrong question... and that the answer was virtualenv - fwiw upgrading django from 1.1.1 to 1.1.3 seems to have solved the problem with the admin interface (odd since i don't think dealing with eggs is something that was mentioned in any of the changelists) but the real solution was to use virtualenv and pip to overlay the the apps with non-egg versions (and to provide a sweat free django update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually specified a directory writable by user that Apache is running your code, for the egg cache directory.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

Comment: don't think that was the issue because apache wasn't complaining, just django.